# How can I create a vtk structure point file from vtk unstructured grid file?

Tags: visualization, vtk

I have an unstructure grid  in vtk file ( with legacy format), these file describe a points, cells and cell type. How can I generate a vtk structured point  from this unstructure grid ?, or a 3d image file (with voxel information)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start converting your vtkUnstructuredGrid to a vtkPolyData, see an example [here](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/GeometryFilter) . Then you can use vtkImplicitModeller to build a vtkImageData (voxels) from your vtkPolyData, see an example [here](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/ImplicitModeller) . These are C++ examples, I'm sure you can find Python examples if needed.